# How to prevent hood covers from slipping up?

Tags: road-bike

I noticed my hood covers (the rubber one) are slipping up -- I pull them down, align with hoods, some time later again (when riding of course) -- they are up. It is really annoying. Granted I put my hands on them, and with the force it is expected in sense of the physics, but I would like them to stay put as they did last year.

Is it a matter of time, I use those hoods and covers the 3rd year, or there is a way/trick to make them sit put and don't move? Hardcore gluing hoods and covers together is not a best option since this in turn blocks access to hood screws and makes replacing bar tape harder.

My brifters are Shimano Sora STI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things I’ve found which help: First, align them properly. There are slots in the plastic of the brifters and little protrusions in the rubber which are supposed to slide into each other. Second: Degrease with some alcohol. Even better is liquid chalk (it’s magnesium carbonate suspended in alcohol, used for climbing and weight lifting) because the magnesium increases friction.

Comment: Ha, great tips, thank you! By pure accident I have some chalk which I used for testing as an addition between tire and inner tube.

Comment: @greenoldman Umm, I'd be real leery of putting chalk anywhere near brifters.  Little sharp mineral crystals aren't going to be good for the shifting mechanism.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Of course you should be very careful where you put it. You absolutely don’t want it on the (inner) cables or shifting mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

I've also got Sora brifters, and the hoods do eventually wear out. I replaced the rubber parts after about 2 years, maybe 20 000km, and several gear cables. They're readily available as spares, but be sure to get the exact model